# How do I copy data across rows depending on the year?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with state policies where an observation is listed only when the policy changes. It looks something like the following:

```
df_have <- data.frame(state = c("AL", "AL", "AL", "AK", "AK", "AZ"),
                 year= c(2015, 2017, 2020, 2015, 2019, 2015),
                 policy= c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1))
```

What I want to do is expand the dataset to all years in-between. But I want to copy the data from the previous year until I reach a change, after which I use the new data until another change, etc. The final dataset should look like this:

```
df_want <- data.frame(state = c("AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AZ", "AZ", "AZ", "AZ", "AZ", "AZ"),
                 year= c(2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020),
                 policy= c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
```

I tried using the uncount() function, but I couldn't figure out how to assign rows based on the original data. The dplyr lag() function looks promising, but I can't figure out how to use it in this instance.

I prefer a solution using dplyr, if possible. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a group by complete to expand the rows and then `fill` the NA elements with the previous non-NA elements in policy and remove the group attribute (`ungroup`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df_have %>%
   group_by(state) %>%
   complete(year = first(year):2020) %>% 
   fill(policy) %>% 
   ungroup
```